# Display post meta conditionally based on it's value

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta

I have a custom field that's a radio button with 3 choices (yes, no, other).

What I'd like to do is the following:

[If custom field value is yes]

Display something here

[elseIf custom field value is no]

Display something here

[elseIf custom field value is other]

[else]

The code I have thus far isn't working, here it is.

```
    <?php 
        global $wp_query;
        $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;                  
        $can_download = get_post_meta($postid, 'enable_downloads', true);
        if ($can_download == 'yes') { ?>

    <?php } elseif ($can_download == 'no') { ?>

    <?php } elseif ($can_download == 'other') { ?>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

No matter what it's just defaulting to yes, I can't figure it out, not sure if this is even the correct way to approach.

Comment: How is that custom field created? plugin or hardcoded in functions.php (if yes post the code)? also do a var_dump($can_download) at the end to see the output.

Comment: It's created using the Advanced Custom Field plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's created with ACF, then the way to call the field is like this:

```
$can_download = get_field('enable_downloads',$postid);
```

so your code should look like:

```
<?php 
        global $wp_query;
        $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;                  
        $can_download = get_field('enable_downloads',$postid);
        if ($can_download == 'yes') { ?>

    <?php } elseif ($can_download == 'no') { ?>

    <?php } elseif ($can_download == 'other') { ?>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <?php } ?>
```